# How can we prove that $‎(D(T),‎\Vert \cdot\Vert‎_{T})‎$‎is Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

If $T$ is a closed operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $‎T(D(T))‎\subseteq‎ D(T)‎$ , how can we prove that $‎(D(T),‎\Vert \cdot\Vert‎_{T})‎$‎  is a Hilbert space?

Comment: What exactly is ∥.∥T?

Comment: we define the graph norm ∥.∥T on D(T) by  ∥f∥2
T= ∥f∥2+ ∥Tf∥2

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange, I hope we can be of help in your studies. In order to encourage answers, it is best to show that you have done some work. Also, you have not used MathJax. You should try to use more and more of it in the future.

Comment: first i have show that there is an Inner Product on space. but i can't prove that how can be a perfect space.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on proper math formatting for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The formula 
$$
\|f\|_T=\sqrt{\|f|^2+\|Tf\|^2}
$$
suggests that the inner product should be 
$$
\langle f,g\rangle_T=\langle f,g\rangle+\langle Tf,Tg\rangle.
$$
Now suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $D(T)$ for the $\|\cdot\|_T$ norm. This implies that $\{f_n\}$ and $\{Tf_n\}$ are Cauchy in the usual norm. Since $T$ is closed, and $H$ is complete, this implies that there exists $f=\lim f_n$ and that $Tf_n\to TF$. So $f\in D(T)$ and $D(T)$ is closed for $\|\cdot\|_T$.